# AngularJS filter by price

Tags: angularjs, filter

Im trying to filter by price, i got a code that its not working properly and i cant seen to know why.

**app.js**

```
app.filter('price', function () {
    return function ( product , value ) {
       // console.log(product, value);
        var filteredItems = [];

        angular.forEach(product , function ( product ) {
            if ( product.price >= value ) {
                filteredItems.push(product);
                console.log(product);
            }
        });
        return filteredItems;
    }
})
```

**the input**

```
<select ng-model="greaterThan" name="price-min">
   <option value="">Desde</option>
   <option value="500">500</option>
   <option value="2000">2000</option>
   <option value="5000">5000</option>
   <option value="20000">20000</option>
</select>
```

**ng-repeat**

```
  <div  ng-repeat="product in cars.records  | price:greaterThan |  filter:query | limitTo:6  " class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--middle  mdl-cell--12-col-phone">
```

link to the website:
(first input)
http://apcarautomoveis.pt/feed.php

Comment: Are you sure it does not work? Remove other filters and check it then. For me that particular filter works like a charm (except the fact that you definitely should change variable names, all are "product" - that's very bad idea ;))

Comment: See that fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/scareddragon/jqqcete8/

Comment: I tried that, remove all inputs / filters, followed your jsfiddle, and still it kinda filters it in a weird way. I am suppose to have around 12 products, all above 100 (price) and its limits it to 3 somehow. and once you step up the price, it behaves weird. take a look:
http://apcarautomoveis.pt/feed.php